# Keeping selection in TTreeView after OnExit

Tags: delphi, treeview

I have a `TTreeView` component I use to display the hierarchical structure in a form and I'd like to be able to select some components and "manipulate" them e.g. clicking a button to move them.

My problem is as soon as I click the button the selected objects vanish.

I've seen that in the `TCustomTreeView` class there is a DoExit procedure:

```pascal
procedure TCustomTreeView.DoExit;
begin
  inherited;
  InvalidateSelectionsRects;
end;
```

I tried to override this method so `InvalidateSelectionRects` is not called to no avail.

Is there a way to keep the (multiple) selected elements while doing interactions outside the TTreeView?

Edit: With the tip provided by [@dwrbudr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/611563/dwrbudr) I was able to list the selected items but the last one doesn't appear:

The code to print the selected items into a memo:

```pascal
procedure TForm1.Button7Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  i: integer;
  Seleccionado: TNodoArbolComponentes;
begin
  Memo1.Lines.Clear;
  for i := 1 to self.TreeView1.SelectionCount - 1 do
  begin
    Seleccionado := (TreeView1.Selections[i] as TNodoArbolComponentes);
    Memo1.Lines.Add(Seleccionado.Componente.Name + ':' + Seleccionado.Componente.ClassName);
  end;
end;
```

I clicked on Panel1, Panel2, Panel4 and Panel3 (in that order) but Panel3, as it was the last one I clicked doesn't appear in the `Selections` list.

I guess I should also check the `TreeView1.Selected` node and see if it has the `TreeView1.Selected.Selected` flag set.

[image: Delphi listing]

Comment: If all this means designtime and not runtime: sure, hold the `Ctrl` key while clicking - because "_doing interactions_" affects everything selected. Which is the whole point of a selection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the `HideSelection` property of the tree view to `False`

```
TreeView.HideSelection := false;
```

Comment: Thanks, it did the trick but I elaborated further in my question.